# Android search activity never been invoked

Tags: java, android

Before I post this, I tried all possible solutions posted here. Finally I got stuck with no luck. I just want to display query string in Search activity. Any help ? Thanks in advance.

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/my_app"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value="com.mycompany.mygoodapp.SearchResultsActivity"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/my_app"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SearchResultsActivity"
        android:label="@string/my_app"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

    </activity>
</application>
```

SearchResultsActivity implementation as below:

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);

    DisplayToast("Here ...");
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        DisplayToast(query);

    }

}

public void DisplayToast(String s) {

    Toast.makeText(SearchResultsActivity.this,
            s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

searchable.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/my_app"
android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

MainActivity :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is   present.

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.mycompany.mygoodapp", "com.mycompany.mygoodapp.SearchResultsActivity");
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(cn));

        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

    }

return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    ///  
    else if(id==R.id.search)
    {
        onSearchRequested();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Main menu layout search menu item:

```
<item
   android:id="@+id/search"
   android:title="@string/search_title"
   android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
   app:showAsAction="always"
   app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView">
```

Comment: "I tried all possible solutions posted here" Which solutions did you try?

Comment: Hi dask. just check this tutorial http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-searchview-in-listview-example-tutorial/ and give a try by yourself.

Comment: @dask check my ans

Answer (score 0):

**you can craete search activity in two way**

**1 way**

menu/options_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
   android:id="@+id/action_search"
   android:icon="@drawable/disha"
   app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
   android:title="search"
   app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

**java code for your activity**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

// Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
SearchManager searchManager =
        (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
SearchView searchView =
        (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
searchView.setSearchableInfo(
        searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

return true;
}
```

**add this in your manifiest file**

```
 <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
```

**searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hint="search hint" />
```

---

**2 Way using custom actionbar**
**or you can also try this**

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.search_layout);

search = (EditText) getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().
        findViewById(R.id.searchfield);

search.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                  KeyEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(getSupportActionBar().DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
        | getSupportActionBar().DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**than create a custom actiob bar layout like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/searchfield"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/custom_search_edit"
android:hint="@string/search_hint"
android:inputType="textFilter"
android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
android:textSize="15sp" />
```

try this and ask me in case of any query